# Unable to access array inside geocoder

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have an array outside the geocoder, but when I want to use that array inside geocoder the values of the array are undefined

```
var titles = new Array(<?php echo implode(",",$titles); ?>);
var length = postCode.length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    geocoder.geocode({'address': postCode[i]}, function(results, status)
    {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {
            lat2 = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            lng2 = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            var Latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lng2);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                              position: Latlng,
                              map: map,
                              title: titles[i], 
                              icon: icon});
            // alert(titles[i]) - all undefined
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure that array doesn't have `var` before its declaration. in JavaScript `var ab` means `ab` is a scope local variable.

Comment: Show us the **generated** JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You could just do

```
var titles = <?php echo json_encode($titles); ?>;
```

Answer (score 1):

The geocoder is asynchronous.  The loop spins through all the possible values of i, leaving i set to postCode.length+1  which is undefined.  This can be addressed with function closure (however, depending on the number of locations you have, you may have issues with the quota or rate limit):

```
function geocodeAddress(index) {
    geocoder.geocode({'address': postCode[index]}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var lat2 = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        var lng2 = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        var Latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lng2);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                           position: Latlng,
                           map: map,
                           title: titles[index], 
                           icon: icon
                         });
     } else { alert("geocode failed:"+status);
   });
}

for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
   geocodeAddress(i);
}
```